# time series with no stochastic trend but deterministic trend

Tags: econometrics

is possible to have a deterministic trend and no stochastic trend? With the dickey fuller test i got a significative p value so it doesn´t have a stochastic trend but i found a deterministic trend. Then how is possible for a time series to be stable with a deterministic trend.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you share more details of the output of the test to help readers understand what is reasonable to suggest. All we have is your interpretation of the result, nothing solid to answer on.

Comment: It is absolutely possible for a series to be stationary around a deterministic trend -- this is exactly what (variants of) the ADF test test.